# List object Binding - altering the model list from within the list item control

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls

**What I have:**

I have a Model object called `Job` which holds a list of `JobTask` 's in an `ObservableCollection` - let's call this `taskList`. I display a `Job` by having an `ItemsControl` - (System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl) which has it's `ItemsSource` bound to the `taskList`. It's `ItemsControl.Template` is displayed by having its `DataTemplate` set to a custom made `UserControl` - let's call this `JobTaskDisplayPanel` which has UIControls relating to a jobTask e.g. title, description, iscomplete etc.. This setup is currently working, and it does display a list of `JobTaskDisplayPanel`'s, with bound information within the ItemsControl.

**Sample code:**

ItemsControl xaml:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="jobsTaskList">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ucs:JobTaskDisplayPanel Margin="4"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

How I bind to this ( I bind to it from code ):

```
jobsTaskList.ItemsSource = currentJob.taskList;
```

**What I want:**

I would like to know how to make changes to the `taskList` (the model list) from each of the individual `JobTaskDisplayPanel`'s, specifically I would like to put a 'Delete' button within each of the `JobTaskDisplayPanel`'s which when pressed, would delete the `JobTask` from it's parent's `taskList`, thus removing it from the applications Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either have your `JobTask` have a property called `Parent` which would reference the `Job` it was associated with, so you can go

```
this.Parent.RemoveTask(this);
```

or I would make use of some kind of EventSystem such as Prism's `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger`. In this case, your `JobTask` would broadcast a message saying to remove itself from whatever owns it, and the `Job` object would subscribe to receive these messages and if it contained the `JobTask` that is in the event message, it would remove it.

Comment: Yes, I have done it the parent-reference method. It feels like a very dirty way of doing things. My first idea of improvement for this situation would be to have the ability to bind to a code-behind method of the parent UserControl, or even better being able to call methods on the parent's DataContext.

Comment: @user989056 It makes sense to me that a `JobTask` would know what `Job` it belongs to, so I don't see anything wrong with a Parent property. You could also rename the probably to something like `Job` if you wanted, since Parent makes it sound like your navigating the UI or doing something hackish.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an ItemsControl, you will not receive a SelectedIndex or SelectedItem when the button is clicked, like you would with a ListBox.  This now forces your item to tell the DataContext managing the Items Collection it needs deleted.

What you need to do is add the delete button to the Panel.  Create a new event in the DataContext of the item, name it something like OnDelete.  Bind the command of the button to a method on your Item which will raise the OnDelete event and pass itself as the sender.  Your parent DataContext, which is where your jobTasksList lives, will need to handle this event and remove it from the ItemsControls Items collection.  You can find the item once you Cast the object sender of the event as your the class of the Item.

You could also pass the item to the Delete method using it as a command parameter, but since you already have to notify the manager of the Items Collection the item is deleted, it doesn't really buy you anything.

Comment: I do not understand how it would be possible to implement what you have said, maybe your terminology is confusing me.

"Create a new event in the DataContext of the item, name it something like OnDelete."

What is the DataContext of the item? Are you talking about the code behind of the `JobTaskDisplayPanel` or the Model class that it represents - `JobTask` ?

Comment: It was a poor choice of words.  That would be whatever class the collection of items is.  So if your items are a collection of JobTask objects, in JobTask you would need to add the OnDelete event.  If you ItemsSource is a collection of JobTaskDisplayPanel then it needs to be in JobTaskDisplayPanel.